# How to pass compiler argument with make?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt5, qt-creator, qmake

With

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -W4
```

I'm trying to pass `W4` to the compiler (Microsoft compiler of VS2019).

However, someway, Qt Creator is passing `W3` afterwards and my `W4` is overwritten. In the compile output panel I see something like:

```
cl -many -other parameters -W4 -and -more -W3 -and -others
```

How to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

[`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake_cxxflags_warn_on) instead of `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` sets the compiler warnings.

Comment: On macOS, with or without it, there is no change in the compiler line (command and arguments). An I see `-Wall -Wextra` in there, however there is no warning.

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing the code. `-Wall -Wextra` do not enable all possible compiler warnings.